# JQUERY/CSS iPad issue: Why double tap needed selecting a radio buttons?

Tags: jquery, ios, css

So I am having this issue where I show a div with a couple radio buttons on hover over a menu item.

1. **My problem:** On iPad and iphone I need to tap on the radio buttons twice until they get selected. (on desktop no problem)
2. **My question:** How do I do it that the user only needs to tap once?
3. **The Code:**

   (a) Here's the code for **showing** that menu **div**:

   ```
           // when entering/leaving the popup, show/hide it
           slide.on('mouseenter', function() {
               $(this).css('display', 'block');                                
           })
           slide.on('mouseleave', function() {
               $(this).css('display', 'none').removeClass('open');
           })
   ```

   (b) Also code, that **bind a click** to the **radio buttons**:

   ```
           // check if filter is applied and add active icon
           $('div.slide > fieldset > input').on('click', function() {

               if ($(this).hasClass('color_input')) {
                     color_kleider.addClass('color_active');
               }

           })
   ```
4. Res:
    
   (a) see the live website: [Outfitya](http://www.outfitya.com/de)

   (b) See this pic here:

[image: menu with radio buttons]

Comment: what is `on('<click></click>'`?

Comment: for ipad, you probably should use <tap></tap> instead of <click></click> - just kidding ;)

Comment: Ok, I click doesnt work either... Any idea how to NOT have to tap twice?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your first touch is activating the `mouseenter` event, your second tap is actually activating the click event.

In your case, I don't believe you need the `mouseenter` event on touch devices, but the first tap should still be activating the `click` event underneath. You might add `this.stopPropgation()` to slide's mouseenter handler and see if the click registers on the first tap.

I would also note that `mouseleave` won't fire on iOS until the *next event* is registered, as in a touch interface, the "cursor" remains where you last touched the screen until it turns up at another location.

Ideally, you should write this so that touch devices do not register any hover event.